# JavaScript return from a function:

Tags: javascript

Is this acceptable in JavaScript? Are there any side effects?

```
function Person()
{
    this.name = function()
    {
        return;
     }
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Are you just asking about the return statement? Have you noticed any side effect? What's the actual problem?

Comment: I would assume so, have you `jsfiddle`'d it? Are you thinking on the lines of, you may not have a name yet so when you want to populate the `Person` function you want to return nothing until the name has been set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid JavaScript. Although the usefulness of it is next to none.